Can't find the sgv id tag on canvas tag?
I try to pointing a dot on a svg file, but I can't find svg id tag in the code.
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import hillstateSvg from "./images/B.svg"; 

const escapeCssSelector = (id) => {
  return `#${CSS.escape(id)}`;
};

const App = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(hillstateSvg)
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((data) => {
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const svgDoc = parser.parseFromString(data, "image/svg+xml");
        const svgElement = svgDoc.documentElement;
        const canvas = canvasRef.current;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        // Set canvas size to match SVG size
        const svgWidth = parseInt(svgElement.getAttribute("width"));
        const svgHeight = parseInt(svgElement.getAttribute("height"));
        canvas.width = svgWidth;
        canvas.height = svgHeight;

        console.log(
          `Canvas size set to width: ${svgWidth}, height: ${svgHeight}`
        );

        const svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
        const img = new Image();
        const svgBlob = new Blob([svgString], {
          type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8",
        });
        const url = URL.createObjectURL(svgBlob);

        img.onload = () => {
          ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
          URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

          console.log("Image loaded and drawn on canvas");

          // Add blue dots
          const ids = ["misa", "misa2"];
          ids.forEach((id) => {
            const targetElement = svgElement.querySelector(
              escapeCssSelector(id)
            );
            if (targetElement) {
              const bbox = targetElement.getBBox();
              if (bbox.width === 0 || bbox.height === 0) {
                // Try getBoundingClientRect if getBBox returns invalid dimensions
                const rect = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect();
                if (rect.width === 0 || rect.height === 0) {
                  console.log(`Element with ID: ${id} has invalid dimensions.`);
                  return;
                } else {
                  console.log(`Element ID: ${id}, rect:`, rect);
                  const cx = rect.left + rect.width / 2;
                  const cy = rect.top + rect.height / 2;
                  ctx.beginPath();
                  ctx.arc(cx, cy, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
                  ctx.fill();
                  console.log("Blue dot drawn using getBoundingClientRect");
                }
              } else {
                const cx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
                const cy = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
                console.log(`Element ID: ${id}, bbox:`, bbox);
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(cx, cy, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
                ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
                ctx.fill();
                console.log("Blue dot drawn using getBBox");
              }
            } else {
              // Log if the element with the ID is not found
              console.log(`Element with ID: ${id} not found.`);
            }
          });
        };

        img.onerror = () => {
          console.error("Failed to load the image.");
        };

        img.src = url;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching or parsing the SVG file:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>SVG Element Click Coordinates</h1>
        <canvas ref={canvasRef} className="canvas-container"></canvas>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

here is my svg file
<svg width="663" height="576" viewBox="0 0 663 576" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<rect id="misa" width="663" height="576" fill="#D9D9D9"/>
</svg>

the error occurs.
Canvas size set to width: 663, height: 576
App.js:43 Image loaded and drawn on canvas
App.js:57 Element with ID: misa has invalid dimensions.
App.js:81 Element with ID: misa2 not found.
App.js:28 Canvas size set to width: 663, height: 576
App.js:43 Image loaded and drawn on canvas
App.js:57 Element with ID: misa has invalid dimensions.
App.js:81 Element with ID: misa2 not found.
the error occurs like this.
How can I solve this error?
Canvas size set to width: 663, height: 576
App.js:43 Image loaded and drawn on canvas
App.js:57 Element with ID: misa has invalid dimensions.
App.js:81 Element with ID: misa2 not found.
App.js:28 Canvas size set to width: 663, height: 576
App.js:43 Image loaded and drawn on canvas
App.js:57 Element with ID: misa has invalid dimensions.
App.js:81 Element with ID: misa2 not found.

I'm unclear what you're trying to achieve, what the error is exactly, or what you're asking. Please state what you expect to happen and what's actually happening. Preferably simplify your code to remove any distractions and create a [mcve]. Thanks.

getBBox() as well as getBoundingClientRect() can only be applied to already rendered elements otherwise it will return 0. That's  probably why you get the invalid dimension error.
